# How do you get the Bucket website endpoint for an S3 bucket setup for static hosting?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

How do you get the generated Bucket website endpoint for an S3 bucket using the AWS CLI?

The closest thing I can find is [get-bucket-website](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/get-bucket-website.html), but it doesn't return the Bucket website endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Website endpoint format is standard and documented: [S3 Website Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html#s3_website_region_endpoints).

From the [official doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteEndpoints.html) regarding the endpoint format:

> Depending on your Region, your Amazon S3 website endpoint follows one
> of these two formats.
>
> - s3-website dash (-) Region ‐ http://**bucket-name**.s3-website-**Region**.amazonaws.com
> - s3-website dot (.) Region ‐ http://**bucket-name**.s3-website.**Region**.amazonaws.com

Comment: so, long story short, you cannot :) I ended up using that format as a temporary solution, I guess it will be the permanent solution. Grazie per aver confermato Filippo ;)

Comment: @Kappacake Di nulla ;)